# Postfix: Python Milter not able to change email header

Tags: python, postfix-mta, mta, milter

I have some servers that create automated emails which all pass through a Postfix MTA. The software that generates the email does not strictly follow RFCs, and sometimes generates emails with duplicate message-ID headers. The software cannot be changed, so I am trying to intercept and fix these messages on their way through the MTA.

I have a milter daemon written in Python that is attempting to remove duplicate message IDs from inbound messages.

The code is below:

```
import Milter
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

file_handler = logging.FileHandler('/var/log/milter.log')
file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(file_handler)

seen_message_ids = set()

class MessageIDMilter(Milter.Base):
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = Milter.uniqueID()

    @Milter.noreply
    def connect(self, IPname, family, hostaddr):
        logger.debug("Milter connected to %s family %s at address %s" % (IPname, family, hostaddr))
        self.IPname = IPname
        self.family = family
        self.hostaddr = hostaddr
        return Milter.CONTINUE

    @Milter.noreply
    def header(self, name, hval):
        logger.debug("Received header %s with value %s" % (name, hval))
        if name.lower() == "message-id":
            logger.debug("Found message ID: %s" % hval)
            if hval in seen_message_ids:
                logger.debug("Deleting duplicate message ID: %s" % hval)
                try:
                    self.chgheader(name, 1, "")
                except Exception as e:
                    logger.error("Error removing from: %s error message: %s" % (name, e))


            else:
                seen_message_ids.add(hval)
        return Milter.CONTINUE

    @Milter.noreply
    def eoh(self):
        logger.debug("Reached end of headers")
        return Milter.ACCEPT

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger.debug("Script started OK")
    Milter.factory = MessageIDMilter
    Milter.runmilter("message-id-milter", "inet:10001@localhost", 0)
```

The script runs and can be called from Postfix. When attempting to delete the duplicate header with chgheader, the following error is thrown:

`2023-02-03 18:22:44,983 ERROR Error removing from: Message-ID error message: cannot change header`

I cannot see anything wrong with this request, nor any other method to remove the header. The docs suggest this should work: https://pythonhosted.org/pymilter/milter_api/smfi_chgheader.html

Comment: Does it work with other headers? If so, then you probably can't change Message-ID. My expectation is that the Message-ID is how the message is identified internally and changing it would require some internal data structures to be updated, and the authors of Postfix didn't want to deal with that.

Comment: The weird thing is that the message IDs are the same, the header is just duplicated exactly. Also it's the Python script that errors, before it returns control to Postfix.

Comment: Yes, my hypothesis is that the Python library knows about this limitation of Postfix and enforces it. But I might be hypothesizing wrong, of course.